# Apply Interface to partial class which returns partial class that needs interface

Tags: c#, interface, partial-classes

I have a suite of web service functions from a 3rd party vendor which I am trying to connect to using a Service Reference. The functions all have a common data structure, but because of the naming convention, they are all brought in as separate classes. I would like to apply an interface to the partial classes that the wizard creates so that I can have one function to populate the common data for each. Here's my problem:

From the import of the service, it creates a series of classes like this:

```
public partial class Service1_Header
{
   public Service1_WSSvcInfo ServiceInfo {get;set;}
}
public partial class Service1_WSSvcInfo
{
   public string SvcName {get;set;}
   public string SvcVersion {get;set;}
}

public partial class Service2_Header
{
   public Service2_WSSvcInfo ServiceInfo {get;set;}
}
public partial class Service2_WSSvcInfo
{
   public string SvcName {get;set;}
   public string SvcVersion {get;set;}
}

public partial class Service3_Header
{
   public Service3_WSSvcInfo ServiceInfo {get;set;}
}
public partial class Service3_WSSvcInfo
{
   public string SvcName {get;set;}
   public string SvcVersion {get;set;}
}
...
```

So I create my interface like this:

```
public interface IHeader
{
    IWSSvcInfo ServiceInfo {get;set;}
}
public interface IWSSvcInfo
{
    string SvcName {get;set;}
    string SvcVersion {get;set;}
}
```

And then create a new file to assign the interfaces to the partial classes like so:

```
public partial class Service1_Header : IHeader
{}
public partial class Service1_WSSvcInfo : IWSSvcInfo
{}
public partial class Service2_Header : IHeader
{}
public partial class Service2_WSSvcInfo : IWSSvcInfo
{}
public partial class Service3_Header : IHeader
{}
public partial class Service3_WSSvcInfo : IWSSvcInfo
{}
...
```

The problem I am having is that it doesn't recognize that I've assigned the interface IWSSvcInfo to Service[X]_WSSvcInfo, so even though the imported Service[X]_Header implements ServiceInfo which returns WSSvcInfo, and I've defined that class as implementing the interface, it says that Service[X]_Header doesn't implement "IWSSvcInfo ServiceInfo".

I've tried generics, and that gets rid of that error, but the problem is 1) the classes I'm working with are complex, nested several levels deep; and 2) even when I was able to get the generic class to work (with really ugly code), it wouldn't call the method because the object I created from the top level class couldn't be recognized as implementing the entire interface structure.

Is there a way to either attach nested interfaces to these nested classes (either with or without generics, but preferably without)? Or is there another method for taking these multiple classes that all have the same structure, and allowing one single method that can populate any of those types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Composition pattern ?

Comment: Possibly. The way it works, when we import the service reference, we end up with Svc1Header, Svc2Header, Svc3Header...etc. They all have nearly identical structures, but because of the way they're named, they come in as distinct classes. We can't edit the services, but we want to apply something to be able to make a single call no matter what the class is to populate it with the default values. Otherwise, we'll have two or three dozen calls that we'll have to wire up individually, and keep track of.

Comment: Adapter pattern?

Comment: I don't think Adapter Pattern gives me the ability to generalize the multiple classes into a single interface that I can send to a single function to populate it with common data.

Comment: The interface contract is that the property must be of type `IWSSvcInfo` and *not* (for example) the concrete type `Service2_WSSvcInfo` even though it *is* a `IWSSvcInfo`. Can you Implement additional explicit interface properties in your partial classes? `IWSSvcInfo IHeader.ServiceInfo { get { return ServiceInfo; } set { ServiceInfo = value; } }`

Comment: That's working. It's not as straightforward as I had hoped, but the one saving grace of the web service we're using is all the classes are named the same suffix so we can do copy/paste once we've built out one of the classes. It just seems ridiculous that it doesn't understand that the class is an implementation of the interface.